# Не получается установить время в timePicker

Tags: android

Приложение компилируется запускается на устройстве. Но когда пробую установить время выходит ошибка и приложение закрывается. Подозреваю что-то с timePicker. Подскажите плз кто знает.

> 01-03 16:12:21.201 27320-27320/info.doma.budilnik E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                       java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.widget.TimePicker.getHour
>                                                                           at info.doma.budilnik.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:48)
>                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3805)
>                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14822)
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:642)
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4457)
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>                                                                           at 
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   01-03 16:12:21.211 107-174/? E/atgles: RecordError 0x0
>   01-03 16:12:21.211 237-237/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity info.doma.budilnik/.MainActivity
>   01-03 16:12:21.231 107-174/? E/atgles: RecordError 0x0

Comment: Покажите, что пишется в ошибке?

Comment: Выходит сообщение "В приложении произошла ошибка" и всё никакой информации.

Comment: В логах должен быть полный текст Exception'а. Найдите его и покажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Сообщение об ошибке вышло большое в окно комментария не вмещается поэтому сделал скриншот он выше в вопросе. Не могу разобраться что тут надо исправлять. Нажимаю на активные ссылки он выбрасывает меня то в  MainActivity то в View или Looper, они создаются автоматически не понимаю что тут надо исправлять.

Comment: добавил сообщение в логе в  текст вопроса выше кода

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод [`getHour()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html#getHour()) класса `TimePicker` доступен начиная с API23. Если минимальная версия API (minSDKversion) вашего приложения меньше  API23 , то вы получаете исключение [NoSuchMethodError](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/NoSuchMethodError.html), которое выбрасывается при невозможности использовать метод (в данном случае он не доступен на более низких API, поддержку которых вы заявили в своем приложении).

Решить эту проблему вы можете увеличив минимальный API приложения до 23, но тогда ваше приложение не запустится на устройствах с ОС ниже Android 6.0, либо вы можете не использовать этот метод и получать нужное вам значение другим способом - например, использовать метод [`getCurrentHour()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html#getCurrentHour()).

Comment: Спасибо большое. Проблема действительно была в этом. Жаль не могу проголосовать за ответ репутации не хватает.